# Populating SQLite database table with foreign key

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently attempting to populate my SQLite database using Android studio. So far I can populate the book table but am unsure to why I cannot populate my chapter table. If I go to view my chapter table I get no output.

As  far as I am aware it is due to the foreign key used in this table.

In my onCreate method have I done something incorrectly with the foreign key?

Below is my code.

**Helper class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "formularyApp.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

//when called creates query
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String sqlBook = "CREATE TABLE book(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, bookName VARCHAR, bookAuthor VARCHAR);";
    String sqlChapter = "CREATE TABLE chapter(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, chapterName VARCHAR, book_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(book_id) REFERENCES book(id))";


    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlBook);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlChapter);


}


public boolean addChapter(String chapterName, Integer book_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("chapterName", chapterName);
    contentValues.put("bookID", book_id);
    db.insert("chapter", null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return true;
}

public boolean addBook(String bookName, String bookAuthor){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("bookName", bookName);
    contentValues.put("bookAuthor", bookAuthor);
    db.insert("book", null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    String sqlBook = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book";
    String sqlChapter = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS chapter";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlBook);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlChapter);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
DatabaseHelper db;

/** Called when the activity is created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db.addBook("Tester Book 5", "Test author");
    db.addChapter("The basics", 5);
    Toast.makeText(this, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    IntroAdapter adapter = new IntroAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your addChapter method you have a typo:

```
contentValues.put("bookID", book_id);
```

should be

```
contentValues.put("book_id", book_id);
```

You are using a wrong column name

Comment: Wow, I looked completely over that. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help ;)